# NavBar Justified stacking vertically on Mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navbar, vertical-alignment

My Top NavBar using bootstrap it's fine on desktop but when I browser my website using my Mobile the navbar links appear stacked vertically, instead of horizontal, why is this happening? any clue?

**I am using bootstrap, here is my code:**

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';
 body {
  background: black url(Images/image.png) no-repeat center center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.navBarLinks {
  color: white;
}
.navBarLinks:hover {
  color: black;
}
.body-content {} .dl-horizontal dt {
  white-space: normal;
}
input,
select,
textarea {
  max-width: 280px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-justified navbar-inverse">
  <li><a class="navBarLinks">Stuff1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="navBarLinks">Stuff2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="navBarLinks">Stuff3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="navBarLinks">Stuff4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="navBarLinks">Stuff5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
//more stuff not relevant
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Bootstrap uses mobile first css.  So when the screen is mobile size then it uses css that displays the list like normal.  However when the screen reaches a min-width of 768 it changes it to display: table-cell.  This is known as a responsive technique using media queries.

Comment: I get it, thank you, so I might need a whole new layout just for the mobile.. Because they way it looks is awful..

Comment: Usually the navigation is hidden and you access it though a hamburger menu icon for mobile view. See the example on the bootstrap site...shrink the window so it is mobile size and you will see how it works. Link to bootstrap navigation https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Comment: Hmmm thank you, maybe you can add that as an answer with a small description and link for details? I accept it as a valid answer in my opinion. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="navBarLinks">Stuff1</a></li>
        <li><a class="navBarLinks">Stuff2</a></li>
        <li><a class="navBarLinks">Stuff3</a></li>
        <li><a class="navBarLinks">Stuff4</a></li>
        <li><a class="navBarLinks">Stuff5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

This is a basic example of what I was talking about...using bootstrap example.

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

When you "Run code snippet" open it up using the full page button and then shrink browser to get a better idea.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked flawlessly !!! I just changed a few details on the style to match my own need, here is my final result: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/359b6862cac06d467acf0c0296a3f6ba